# How do I actually spend a Virgin Experience electronic Cineworld voucher at Cineworld?

Tags: united-kingdom, customer-service

I have an electronic [Virgin Experience voucher](https://www.virginexperiencedays.co.uk/product/cineworld-cinema-tickets-for-two) for cinema tickets for two at Cineworld.

The voucher has a serial number (comprising letters and numbers) and a PIN.

The Virgin Experience guidance directs me to book directly with Cineworld; however, the telephone line for Cineworld no longer accepts bookings and the Cineworld website only accepts fully numeric voucher codes!

Virgin Experience customer support provided via Social Media has so far failed to understand my query or give any advice beyond re-reading their website.

How do I actually buy cinema tickets with a Virgin Experience voucher?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you read the reviews on the page you linked to it seems other people have had the same issue you are having. Is there a way to log in on the Virgin site and redeem the voucher that way?

Comment: (I should have been clearer, I meant "redeem the Virgin voucher for Cineworld vouchers" which you can then redeem in turn on the Cineworld site for actual cinema tickets.)